# Laravel 5.0 data Insertion using bootstrap3 form

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I am trying to insert data into my database name `Client` using a bootstrap form. But if I click submit button the page is just directed to `newClinetForm` page without inserting any value into the Client database. I am using laravel version 5.0.

This is the Form part of `newClientForm` blade template:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{url('clients/newClientForm')}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token() }}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="ClientName" placeholder="Erfan">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Client ID</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="ClientID" placeholder="Ect112">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone No.</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="Phone" placeholder="01XX-XXXXXXX">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
</form>
```

Instead of `csrf_token()` I tried `Session::token()` but didn't help either.

This is my controller part:

```
public function newClientFormIndex(){
    return view('clients.newClientForm');
}

public function store(Request $request) {
    $client = new Client();
    $client->ClientID = $request->ClientID;
    $client->ClientName = $request->ClientName;
    $client->Phone = $request->Phone;
    $client->save();
}
```

This is the Model part:

```
class Client extends Model {
    protected $table = 'clients';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'ClientID';
    protected $fillable = ['ClientID', 'ClientName', 'Phone'];
}
```

This is the Route part:

```
Route::resource('clients/newClientForm', 'IspController@newClientFormIndex');
```

I can't find where the error is.

Comment: in your controller you are rendering the view without any connection to store function which you are using to save data. what are contents of your router file ?

Comment: Guys I've found the error. Problem was in the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `newClientFormIndex` you are not calling the `store` function.
Also, it might be worth differentiating the routes to display the form and the one to actually save data, something like:

```
Route::get('clients/newClientForm', 'IspController@newClientFormIndex');
Route::post('clients/newClientForm', 'IspController@store');
```

And then changing your store method to redirect to the form:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $client = new Client();
    $client->ClientID = $request->ClientID;
    $client->ClientName = $request->ClientName;
    $client->Phone = $request->Phone;
    $client->save();
    return redirect('clients/newClientForm');
}
```

This to avoid form re-submission.

Comment: yah, I'd noticed the same thing a while ago and corrected it !